# Accessing client sent headers behind a load balancer

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I just implemented **OAuth** on my server. 
To authenticate I need to pass the token as a `"Header"` as key `"Authorization"`.

This works great locally but when I deploy this code to my production server since the system is behind a beanstalk load balancer, I don't get any Headers on my individual EC2 instances when PHP runs.

```
             +---------------+     +----------------+ 
             |               |     |                | 
+----------> |  Load Balancer+---> |    EC2 Server  | 
             |               |     |                | 
             |               |     |                | 
             +----------+----+     +----------------+ 
                        |                             
                        |          +-----------------+
                        |          |                 |
                        |          |    EC2 Server   |
                        +--------> |                 |
                                   |                 |
                                   +-----------------+
```

I originally had the same problem with the client ip where the servers would give me back the load balancer ip for `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']`. I fixed by doing this

```
if (getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR')) {
    $ip_array = explode(",", getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'));
    $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] = trim($ip_array[0]);
}
```

On my index.php I tried doing  `die(var_dump($_SERVER))`. 
But I see no reference to any of the headers I've sent.

I do see *HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR*, *HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PORT*, *HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO* but nothing relating to headers.

How can I get the headers on my individual servers after passing through the beanstalk load balancer?

Comment: What about `getallheaders()`?  http://php.net/manual/en/function.getallheaders.php

Comment: Ahh that actually works! So strange

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The stuff returned in `$_[SERVER]` apparently includes a copy of *some* of the headers and their values, with `HTTP_` tacked on to the front, dashes changed to underscores, and the keys coerced to all-caps (headers on the wire aren't actually case-sensitive, but when you're dealing with an associative array, you need the keys in a canonical form)... it was probably all done that way for a really good legacy reason that few people remember any more.

The real request headers are accessible through the [`getallheaders()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getallheaders.php) function, at least if you're using an Apache web server.